# AWS worker tier cron with ZF2 yielding 404, but working locally?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cron, zend-framework2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We currently have set up an Elastic Beanstalk worker tier with several cron jobs. They are recognized but when it tries to execute them, it gives us a 404 status code. Running the exact same url on our local server and the cloud server we're migrating from both execute the command correctly.

Zend is definitely up and running because I had to fix an issue that was causing a redirect on the cron jobs before I could even get to the 404, and now I'm just confused what the issue is.

```
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [15/Nov/2016:19:56:59 +0000] "POST /review/generate-reports HTTP/1.1" 404 246 "-" "aws-sqsd/2.3"

2016-11-15T19:56:59Z message: sent to http://localhost:80/review/generate-reports
2016-11-15T19:56:59Z http-err: e1ad030b-db39-475a-bfc9-35ceb3a7abaa (1) 404 - 0.002
```

All of the configuration settings for EB were left alone when creating the worker tier, so they're still set to the defaults. The cron.yaml declaration is as follows:

```
version: 1
cron:
 - name: "generate-reports"
   url: "/review/generate-reports"
   schedule: "* * * * *"
```

Answer (score 0):

If this working locally check php extensions that you use in your application exists in your server sometimes zf giving 404 error not 500 if exception was raised in runtime process, exception might be raised if application couldn't find required class or function that some php extension provide.